# Changing the pitch of a sound in realtime (Swift)

Tags: swift, audio, pitch

I have been trying, for the past weeks, to find a simple way to control audio frequency (I.E. change the pitch of an audio file) from within swift in realtime.
I have tried with AVAudioPlayer.rate but that only changes the speed.
I even tried connecting an AVAudioUnitTimePitch to an audio engine with no success.
AVAudioUnitTimePitch just gives me an error, and rate changes the playback  speed which is not what I need.
What I would like to do is, make a sound higher or lower pitch, say from -1.0 to 2.0 (audio source.duration/2 so it would play twice as fast.

Do you guys know of any way to do this even  if I have to use external libraries or classes?

Thank you, I am stumped as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Audio Unit API, the iOS built-in kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch Audio Unit component can be used to change pitch while playing audio at the same speed.  e.g. the kNewTimePitchParam_Rate and kNewTimePitchParam_Pitch parameters are independent.

The Audio Unit framework has a (currently non-deprecated) C API, but one can call C API functions from Swift code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.So I could somehow attach this to an AVAudioNode or..? I'm confused as to how to apply this, more so because it is a C API. Any hints?

Comment: Alright so, I got AVAudioUnitTimePitch to work but htis was nto really what I'm loking for, this does time stretching and does unnecessary processing, what I want to do is downsample so that the audio plays at lower speed.

Comment: You could try looking into MIDI sampler synthesis engines, and see if that does what you want.